# Azure App Service not loading React(Vite) Client App

Tags: react-native, .net-6.0, vite

I have an application that uses .net 6 backend and react frontend(Vite TSX). The application runs locally and it is able to display data from .NET controller. But when its deployed to an app service i get the following issue.

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec`.

It is displaying error from the following javascript file referenced in index.html

[image]